# can i know why my aggregate result does not work

Tags: java, aggregation, rules, fuzzy

acuteStress=Math.min(t1,Math.min(t2,Math.min(t3,Math.min(t4,Math.min(t5,Math.min(t6,Math.min(t7,Math.min(t8,Math.min(t13,Math.min(t14,Math.min(t15,Math.min(t16,Math.min(t17,Math.min(t18,Math.min(t19,Math.min(t20,Math.min(t37,Math.min(t38.Math.min(t39,Math.min(t40,Math.min(t109,Math.min(t110,Math.min(t111,Math.min(t112,Math.min(t145,Math.min(t146,Math.min(t147,Math.min(t148,Math.min()))))))))))))))))))))))))))));

```
   episodicStress=Math.min(t9,Math.min(t10,Math.min(t11,Math.min(t12,Math.min(t21,Math.min(t22,Math.min(t23,Math.min(t24,Math.min(t25,Math.min(t26,Math.min(t27,Math.min(t28,Math.min(t29,Math.min(t30,Math.min(t31,Math.min(t32,Math.min(t33,Math.min(t34,Math.min(t35,Math.min(t36,Math.min(t41,Math.min(t42,Math.min(t43,Math.min(t44,Math.min(t45,Math.min(t46,Math.min(t47,Math.min(t48,Math.min(t49,Math.min(t50,Math.min(t51,Math.min(t52,Math.min(t53,Math.min(t54,Math.min(t55,Math.min(t56,Math.min(t57,Math.min(t58,Math.min(t59,Math.min(t60,Math.min(t61,Math.min(t62,Math.min(t63,Math.min(t64,Math.min(t65,Math.min(t66,Math.min(t67,Math.min(t68,Math.min(t69,Math.min(t70,Math.min(t71,Math.min(t72,Math.min(t73,Math.min(t74,Math.min(t75,Math.min(t76,Math.min(t77,Math.min(t78,Math.min(t79,Math.min(t80,Math.min(t81,Math.min(t82,Math.min(t83,Math.min(t84,Math.min(t85,Math.min(t86,Math.min(t87,Math.min(t88,Math.min(t89,Math.min(t90,Math.min(t91,Math.min(t92,Math.min(t93,Math.min(t94,Math.min(t95,Math.min(t96,Math.min(t97,Math.min(t98,Math.min(t99,Math.min(t100,Math.min(t101,Math.min(t102,Math.min(t103,Math.min(t104,Math.min(t113,Math.min(t114,Math.min(t115,Math.min(t116,Math.min(t117,Math.min(t118,Math.min(t119,Math.min(t120,Math.min(t121,Math.min(t122,Math.min(t123,Math.min(t124,Math.min(t125,Math.min(t126,Math.min(t127,Math.min(t128,Math.min(t133,Math.min(t134,Math.min(t135,Math.min(t136,Math.min(t149,Math.min(t150,Math.min(t151,Math.min(t152,Math.min(t153,Math.min(t154,Math.min(t155,Math.min(t156,Math.min(t157,Math.min(t158,Math.min(t159,Math.min(t160,Math.min(t169,Math.min(t170,Math.min(t171,Math.min(t172,Math.min(t181,Math.min(t182,Math.min(t183,Math.min(t184,Math.min())))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))) ;
   
   chronicStress=Math.min(t105,Math.min(t106,Math.min(t107,Math.min(t108,Math.min(t129,Math.min(t130,Math.min(t131,Math.min(t132,Math.min(t137,Math.min(t138,Math.min(t139,Math.min(t140,Math.min(t141,Math.min(t142,Math.min(t143,Math.min(t144,Math.min(t161,Math.min(t162,Math.min(t163,Math.min(t164,Math.min(t165,Math.min(t166,Math.min(t167,Math.min(t168,Math.min(t173,Math.min(t174,Math.min(t175,Math.min(t176,Math.min(t177,Math.min(t178,Math.min(t179,Math.min(t180,Math.min(t185,Math.min(t186,Math.min(t187,Math.min(t188,Math.min(t189,Math.min(t190,Math.min(t191,Math.min(t192,Math.min(t193,Math.min(t194,Math.min(t195,Math.min(t196,Math.min(t197,Math.min(t198,Math.min(t199,Math.min(t200,Math.min(t201,Math.min(t202,Math.min(t203,Math.min(t204,Math.min(t205,Math.min(t206,Math.min(t207,Math.min(t208,Math.min(t209,Math.min(t210,Math.min(t211,Math.min(t212,Math.min(t213,Math.min(t214,Math.min(t215,Math.min(t216,Math.min()))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))));
```

Comment: It's say..... 

"double cannot be dereferenced

not suitable method found for min ( no arguments) 
method Math.min(int,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t38.Math` -> `t38,Math`

`Math.min(t148,Math.min())` -> `t148`

`Math.min(t184,Math.min())` -> `t184`

`Math.min(t216,Math.min())` -> `t216`